# Input para filtro de búsqueda jQuery solo trae texto

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de implementar un cuadro de búsqueda sencillo que me filtre los títulos `<h3>` de cada **`card`** que tengo en mi página.

El problema es que únicamente me trae resultados en texto, y me oculta la imagen que tengo junto con la clase `blog-inner`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema está en el `script` de jQuery.

Intenté en un principio aplicar el filtro al identificador `#myDIV` y que me traiga los campos `<h3>` y aunque parecía funcionar dejándome la imagen, solo me ocultaba los demás textos.

```
$("#myDIV h3").filter(function() {
```

También estuve moviendo de lugar el filtro de búsqueda y el ID `#myDIV` para ver si lograba traer en mis resultados lo contenido dentro de los modales agregando un filtro global en la función `*`, pero tampoco funcionó.

Estuve probando [estos *snipets*](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_filters.asp) sin mucho éxito

Acepto modificaciones en el filtro con Jquery o añadir incluso otro recurso para llegar al resultado que deseo.

Estaré muy atento, gracias!

También tengo el código en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/wQZKPz)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h3{
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.search{
  padding: 50px 55px;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-modal {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border-radius: 6px;
background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
border: none;
padding-left: 17px;
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 90%;
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
margin: 0;
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content .item-details {
margin: 30px 0;
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
position: absolute;
width: 45px;
height: 45px;
background-color: transparent;
top: 25px;
right: 45px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
opacity: 0.3;
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
height: 45px;
width: 1px;
margin-left: 35px;
background-color: #777;
transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
/* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
/* Safari and Chrome */
z-index: 1051;
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
height: 45px;
width: 1px;
background-color: #777;
transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* Safari and Chrome */
z-index: 1052;
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-backdrop {
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Titulo</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://tarjetero.co/intranet/sm/css/bootstrap.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://tarjetero.co/intranet/sm/css/style.css'>

  
</head>

<body>
 <div id="fh5co-blog-section">

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center fh5co-heading">
      <h2>Nuestras Sedes</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
       <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
     </div>





 <!--INICIO MAPAS-->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="search">
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda.."></div>
      
<div id="myDIV">
  
     <!--Mapa1-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">Sede Colombia</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!--Mapa2-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal">Sede Seul</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!--Mapa3-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal3" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal3" data-toggle="modal">Sede Japón</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!--Mapa4-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal4" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal4" data-toggle="modal">Oficinas India</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!--Mapa5-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal5" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal5" data-toggle="modal">Planta Irlanda</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!--Mapa6-->
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div class="blog-inner">
     <a href="#modal6" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
    <div class="desc">
     <h3><a href="#modal6" data-toggle="modal">Planta Hawai</a></h3>
    </div>
       </div>
     </div>


       </div><!--row-->
   </div>


   <!-------------------------------------------->

 <!-- Modal 1-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Sede Principal Colombia</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Bogotá - Colombia
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Modal 2-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Sede Administrativa Seul</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Seul - Corea del Sur
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Modal 3-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Sede Operativa Japon</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Tokio, Japón
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Modal 4-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Oficinas India</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Nueva Delhi, India
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Modal 5-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Planta Irlanda</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Dublín, Irlanda
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   <!-- Modal 6-->
     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <div class="lr">
                     <div class="rl">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <div class="modal-body">
                             <h2>Planta Hawai</h2>
                             <hr><br>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728"
                 width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br><br><hr>
               <p><b>Dirección:</b> Honolulu - Hawai
        <br>
        <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
        </p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

   </div>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que la imagen y el texto están dentro del `div.blog-inner` utiliza esa clase en lugar del selector universal `*` y asi el filtro lo muestra todo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV .blog-inner").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search {
  padding: 50px 55px;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-modal {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content .item-details {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 25px;
  right: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
  height: 45px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  background-color: #777;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1051;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
  height: 45px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #777;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1052;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-backdrop {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Titulo</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://tarjetero.co/intranet/sm/css/bootstrap.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://tarjetero.co/intranet/sm/css/style.css'>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="fh5co-blog-section">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center fh5co-heading">
          <h2>Nuestras Sedes</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
    </div>





    <!--INICIO MAPAS-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="search">
          <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda.."></div>

        <div id="myDIV">

          <!--Mapa1-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">Sede Colombia</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Mapa2-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal">Sede Seul</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Mapa3-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal3" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal3" data-toggle="modal">Sede Japón</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Mapa4-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal4" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal4" data-toggle="modal">Oficinas India</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Mapa5-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal5" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal5" data-toggle="modal">Planta Irlanda</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Mapa6-->
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="blog-inner">
              <a href="#modal6" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="Mapa"></a>
              <div class="desc">
                <h3><a href="#modal6" data-toggle="modal">Planta Hawai</a></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>


      <!-------------------------------------------->

      <!-- Modal 1-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Sede Principal Colombia</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Bogotá - Colombia
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal 2-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Sede Administrativa Seul</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Seul - Corea del Sur
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal 3-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Sede Operativa Japon</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Tokio, Japón
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal 4-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Oficinas India</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Nueva Delhi, India
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal 5-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Planta Irlanda</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Dublín, Irlanda
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal 6-->
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2>Planta Hawai</h2>
                  <hr><br>
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12420.601524132726!2d-77.0365298!3d38.8976763!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sCasa+Blanca!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1543869223728" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:0;width: -webkit-fill-available;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <br><br>
                  <hr>
                  <p><b>Dirección:</b> Honolulu - Hawai
                    <br>
                    <b>Teléfonos:</b> (2) 123 4567
                  </p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Funciona! Es posible filtrar el resultado con el contenido que está dentro de los modales?

Comment: ¿Buscar por palabras que esten en las modales y que se muestre la sede correspondiente? Si es eso lo que quieres hacer sería algo mas complicado

Comment: con un `data-filter` tal vez?

Comment: Ok, al final logré colocar dentro de la info de los modales la clase `blog-inner` sin que me desordenara el contenido.

Comment: Hola @blonfu quisiera aplicar este código a mi proyecto pero tengo cerca de 40 mapas, ¿existe una forma de depurar un poco el código para que no sea tan extenso y repetitivo? Estoy con html estático, pero puedo aplicarlo con cualquier lenguaje si es necesario

Comment: @LauraZ el código no es mío, yo solo cambié un selector para intentar resolver el problema del OP. Esto no funciona como un foro, si tienes una duda deberías formular tu propia pregunta explicando tu caso concreto para que la gente pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias @blonfu tomaré en cuenta tu comentario :)