# Mostrar videos de youtube en un modal según el botón presionado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, youtube

Tengo varios botones que abren videos de youtube. Ocurre que el `data-target` apunta al mismo código modal en los dos botones. Cada botón debería llevar su enlace de video a la ventana modal para su apertura correspondiente. Se que una posibilidad es crear un código modal por cada botón, pero no es lo propio ya que se duplicaría mucho código.
La idea es que cada botón tenga su propio enlace en el name o en el value o en el id, para que en el código de la ventana modal ejecute el correspondiente video. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!-- BOTÓN1 QUE ABRE VENTANA MODAL CON VIDEO YOUTUBE -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  VIDEO 1
</button>

<!-- BOTÓN2 QUE ABRE VENTANA MODAL CON VIDEO YOUTUBE -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  VIDEO 2
</button>

<!-- CÓDIGO DE VENTANA MODAL -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe width="100%" height="" autoplay src="aqui va el enlace del video de youtube" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te comparto una pregunta similar con unas excelentes respuestas. Puedes revisarla aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267876/generar-plantilla-html

Comment: podrías probar a usar jquery y con este solo cambiar el atributo src, otros datos que ocupes cambiar y después   mostrarlo con $(id del modal).modal('show');